# Dead Letter Arriving When Spray-Servlet Loads

Tags: tomcat, akka, spray, spray-routing

I'm working with `spray-servlet` (using Tomcat 8 as the servlet container) and `spray-routing`.

Whenever I deploy my WAR, my `serviceActor` receives a message. This message goes to a specific path and it's always the same path and always once. The `sender` is the `system`'s dead letters actor.

I am not sure where this message is coming from. Would appreciate any help debugging this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is mostly the case, the issue was user error.

My routes were defined like this:

```
... {
    doStuff()
    complete(OK)
}
```

Causing the loading phase of `spray-routing` to execute the code before stopping at `complete`.

I changed my code to look like this:

```
... {
    complete {
        doStuff()
        OK
    }
}
```

And everything's working as it should.